# How to fix Ajax fetch nothing from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, object

I have a hard time finding my mistake in this code. I have a search bar and I'd use ajax so that the data will fetch automatically.

---

This is my html file.

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="bootstrap4/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
             function loadproducts()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("search");
        if(name)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                contentType:false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                data: {
                    products:name,
                },
                url: 'loadproducts.php',
                success: function (response){
                    $('#product_area').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#product_area').html("No Product found!");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="loadproducts();">
<div id="product_area">

</div>
</body>
</html>

----------
This is my loadproducts.php file



<?php
    include('server/connection.php');

    if (isset($_POST['products'])){

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['products']);

        $show   = "SELECT product_name,sell_price FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '$name%' ";
        $query  = mysqli_query($db,$show);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<p>".$row['product_name']."</p>";
                echo "<p>".$row['sell_price']."</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Ill tried putting alert("called"); function on the ajax success and the alert is activated but still no output show. I also edit the `var name = document.getElementById("search");` to `var name = document.getElementById("#search");` but it pass straight to the else statement.Can someone site the problem of this code?

Comment: If you're backend is expecting the post to have a query string on it consisting of `product=valueFromSearchInput`, then you need to remove `processData:false` from the options.  This option tells jQuery to not convert the data option to a query string.

Comment: Also not sure why you are setting `contentType:false` for either

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I remove the `processData:false` and `contentType:false` it shows now. I'd put those two because there's an error when I go to the console to check if the js is working. I'd remove it now and it's good now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're accessing the actual HTML element. You want the value, so use `.value`:

```
var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
```

Or if you prefer, you can simplify this down with jQuery:

```
var name = $("#search").val();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd this code instead of my code.My problem is fix now. Thanks.